# Composite Key validation in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**I am trying the below query in Laravel 5.1**

```
Select * from tblSubCategory 
Where SubCategoryID != 1 and CategoryID = 1 and SubCategory = 'test data';
```

**Below is my code in Laravel**

```
$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'SubCategory' => 'required|max:100|min:5|unique:tblsubcategory,SubCategory,'
        .''.$request->input('CategoryID')
        .',CategoryID,SubCategoryID,'.$request->input('SubCategoryID')

]);
```

**Above expression is producing below query.**

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `tblsubcategory` 
where `SubCategory` = 'under website1' and `CategoryID` <> 1 and `SubCategoryID` = 1
```

**Unique Key**

```
UNIQUE KEY `UK_tblSubCategory_SubCategory_CategoryID` (`CategoryID`,`SubCategory`);
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @guessimtoolate, i guess it's why he got different query for the validator.

Answer (score 1):

## **Approach:1: Compatible with Laravel : 5.***

**On the command line**:`composer require felixkiss/uniquewith-validator:2.*`

**Add the following to your** `providers array` in `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => array(
    'Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider',
),

$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'SubCategory' => 'required|max:100|min:5|unique_with:tblsubcategory,CategoryID',
    'CategoryID' => 'required',
]);
```

## **Approach:2**

```
$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'SubCategory' => 'unique:tblsubcategory,SubCategory,'
                     .$request->input('SubCategoryID') 
                     .',SubCategoryID,CategoryID,'
                     .$request->input('CategoryID')
]);

if ($v->fails()) {
    return \Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($v)
                ->withInput();
}
```